# How to simplify this python script?

Tags: python

I'm making a script in python and I'm new to python. Could someone help me simplify this.

```
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="6":
    print("Button1")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="7":
    print("Button2")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="8":
    print("Button3")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="9":
    print("Button4")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="A":
    print("Button5")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="B":
    print("Button6")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="C":
    print("Button7")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="D":
    print("Button8")
```

EDIT: I made a mistake with the button sequence.

Comment: replace it with a dictionary with tuples as keys. If you are meant to print `"Button1"` no matter what, just do `print("Button1")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4] in "6789ABCD":
    print("Button1")
```